# cPanel's AutoSSL limits

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I wasn't able to find enough information about this cool feature and I'm hoping someone help me out.

According to cPanel documentation, AutoSSL (by Comodo) issues maximum 200 certificates per domain / virtual host :
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Manage+AutoSSL

What does it mean exactly? If I have 300 domains on WHM, cPanel only issues certificates for maximum 200 of them?

Yes, it's cool to have free certificates but honestly the most attractive part of this deal is "auto SSL installation". If this feature is still too experimental, what do you suggest for auto implementing DV SSLs that overcomes the validation steps?

Answer (score 0):

In short,
This means that "each" hosting account can generate a maximum of 200 certificates.
Taking into consideration that each account has its own virtual host.